# 2009 wireless keyboard giving serious lag on macbook pro

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, bluetooth

I've got a 2009 wireless keyboard connecting to a 2012 Macbook Pro running El Capitan, and it's giving me serious lags; occasionally sticking; sometimes just disconnecting.

Things I've tried thus far include

- resetting PRAM
- resetting the bluetooth keyboard
- running it in safe mode

and nothing seems to solve the problem. Any thoughts on this? Am I doomed? What's the next troubleshooting step?

Thanks!

Comment: Putting in fresh batteries always solves these issues with my 2006 Apple Wireless keyboard

Answer (score 1):

Without being cheeky, it could just be a sign of age. The keyboard itself is 9 years old and the MBP is 6 years old.

You did well to get so long out of the keyboard, but I wouldn't be too sure what specifically could be wrong with it or if it would be worth fixing.

I wouldn't rule out a hardware problem caused by 9 years of usage.